# BMP180 wrong reading

Tags: sensor, bmp180

I connected my BMP180 on Raspberry Pi, temerature reading is correct, but pressure reading is incorect. It says `Pressure=100448.00Pa`, `Sealevel Pressure=10450.00Pa` while my local weather station says 1020hPa. I followed Adafruit tutorial, and I'm using their library.

Comment: When you have only 2 measurements, and they differ, you cannot make any statements which one of them is wrong. You need more measurements. Find at least one more source of current barometric pressure, or take your setup to another location with a known and reliable barometric pressure reading and test there to see if the results still differ

Comment: I compared it to 3 more results...

Comment: Are you sure you are not just confusing the scale?  1020hPa is 102000.00Pa which is fairly close to 100450.00Pa.  You probably need to calibrate the sensor.

Comment: 3 more results from the same sensors? Or did you use different equipment? My comments are specifically telling you to use different sources of barometric pressure readings to verify if it is the BMP180 that is wrong or your local weather station (which you cannot determine by having readings only from those 2). 100450Pa (1005hPa) is a perfectly acceptable reading.

Comment: I'm not confusing the scale...

1 reslut from my sensor, 2 results from local pws, and 1 result from national weather station. All 3 results matched only mine didn't.  Like now it's reading presure = 999.58hPa while other stations are reading 1012-1013hPa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite have an answer for you but this might lead you to a solution.

> It says Pressure=100448.00Pa, Sealevel Pressure=10450.00Pa while my local weather station says 1020hPa.

So this is a discrepancy of a few kPa.  However, note that weather stations report the pressure *adjusted for temperature and altitude*.  Unfortunately the altitude adjustment actually *adds* (unless you are below sea level) and so does the temperature if you are above ~freezing.

I have some C++ code for the Adafruit BMP085 board; I believe they say these two devices have the exact same interface (the 180 is a replacement model).

[BMP085_C++.tar.bz2](http://cognitivedissonance.ca/cogware/BMP085/)

To unpack that: `tar -xvjf BMP085_C++.tar.bz2`.

I can promise you it works as I have been using it to record data for more than a year and occasionally check the pressure against local weather stations (well, right now I'm 0.2 kPA high).  There's a README in there which will tell you how to how to compile a quick demo which will spit out the pressure adjusted for temperature but not altitude (since it does not know the altitude).  The adjust for temperature formula is in `adjustedPressure()`.

There's a constant in there (`SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE`) and a static function (`getMeanPressure()`) you can calculate the altitude adjustment with.  Here's the formula, which I must have gotten online somewhere:

```
pow(1.0 - (height/44330.0), 5.255) * SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE
```

Here 'height' is in meters and `SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE` is 101.325.  In case this is not clear, it means 1.0 - (height/44330.0) raised to the power of 5.255, times mean sea level pressure.  This is for kPa.

You would subtract that from sea level pressure then add the difference to the adjusted for temperature figure.  That should nearly match the number from local weather.

Comment: With this formula I get let's say correct data. With formula I got 1013hPa but when I add 13hPa(I noticed that data is allways 13hPa lower) to my pressure I got 1011hPa wich is more close to my local pws. I'll do some more test to view wich one is more accurate, but I think I'll go with this formula